# What's the meaning of 'by' in the sentence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions

He did well **by** his children.

I found the meaning of 'by'- **In relation to/Concerning.**

But the sentence seems ambiguous to me.... Plz clarify the grammar behind the use of by like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more idiomatic phrase (at least to me as a British English speaker) would be to "*do right by*", which [means](https://www.wordnik.com/words/do%20right%20by) *to treat, deal with, or act toward (someone) in a morally just, socially honourable fashion*. To do 'well' by them would carry pretty much the same meaning, but perhaps focusing on the *success* that they may have rather than just the moral intent. Doing right by one's children might suggest raising them appropriately, taking good care of them within one's means. Doing *well* by them might mean they achieved more than someone else with the same good intent but less means? Context should help you see that.

I would have to disagree with any answer that suggests 'by' simply means 'for' or 'for the benefit of' in this construction. When measuring something against a standard we often say that something is right '*by*' that standard. For example, "*fine by me*" is extremely common to mean that you judge something to be fine and has nothing to do with whether you are the beneficiary or not. Nor does this use of 'by' simply mean 'on behalf of', as this can mean doing something for another that they would ordinarily have done themselves, or in the manner they request. Most would agree that parenting, the subject of your example, does not always involve giving children what they *want* but what they *need*.

Comment: Of course I have a reputable dictionary saying that **one** of the meanings of “by” is “on behalf of,” which does mean “for the benefit of.” See #8 of https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/by

Comment: @JeffMorrow I disagree. Doing something 'on behalf' of someone is like surrogacy. It can be something they would otherwise do themselves. If children raised themselves they would eat ice-cream for breakfast. That's not what parents give them. They do right *by* them, not necessarily the things they would do themselves.

Comment: I agree that “do X on behalf of Y” **can** mean doing X as a surrogate for Y. In which case, we could indeed say “do X **for** Y” as in “I mailed it for him.” But the more common use of “on behalf of” is “for the benefit of.” You keep talking about “right by me” and “fine by me,” which is not the phrase asked about. “Well” is not about surrogacy.

Comment: @JeffMorrow Yes it can mean that. So if your comment were an answer, it would be wrong. This question is about an idiom with a specific meaning. Lots of people spouting unsustainable opinion about the meaning of individual words and what they could mean in other contexts is helping nobody. The OP has asked about the meaning of 'by' in this example, not the meaning of 'well'.

Comment: @JeffMorrow I take on board that I haven't distinguished between the more common idiom and the OP's example and have updated accordingly. I've also incorporated my refuting of your comment in the answer.

Comment: I found this meaning by searching "do well by"now in MacMillan dictionary :—
**to treat someone in a fair or generous way**
 The president called on companies to do well by their employees.

Comment: I think :-He did well by his children mean He treat his children in a fair and generous way. Here by mean 'in relation to', It could mean His fair and generous behavior in relation to/concerning his children. Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

In this construction, “by” has the meaning “on behalf of” or “for the benefit of.”

You are correct that the meaning is somewhat vague.

> He did well by his children

means

> He did [something] for the benefit of his children well.

Exactly what he did well is not specified. This particular locution is often used to mean that the benefit provided was financial. However, context may make clear that a benefit of a different kind is intended.

> He was an emotionally distant father, but he was diligent and generous in ensuring his children’s education. At least in that regard, he did well by his children.

In that context, it is clear that the benefit bestowed was educational.

**EDIT**: Astralbee has focused on the more common phrase “did right by.” I fully agree that replacing “well” with the more specific word “right” does make clear that the benefit or benefits provided were what was morally due. I am not convinced that “well” conveys the same sense of moral approval.

Comment: I have to disagree with the main part of your answer which suggests 'by' means 'for'. I'd go as far as to say it is misleading.

Comment: Do you agree that “on behalf of” means “for the benefit of”? Or do you mean that “by” in this sense does not mean “on behalf of”? Note that I did not say “by” means “for.”

Comment: No Jeff, I'd have to disagree with that as they are not the same. See my updated answer for details as to why. The more you argue, the further you get from the meaning of what is an idiomatic phrase.

Comment: I am not talking about “do right by them.” That is not what the original question was about. I have no problem with your analysis of “right by them.”

Comment: The question is about a single word - "by", and its meaning in this context. The context of the two idioms is exactly the same, even if the meaning is not.

Comment: We disagree. No need to discuss further.